# Spring Integration: FileReadingMessageSource properties need to read from FTP inbox

Tags: spring, spring-integration

What are the FileReadingMessageSource properties need to read from FTP inbox?

The FTP inbox location we are attempting to read from is here: /users/chroot/mecssn/incoming/archive. This directory is owned by the wasadm user who runs WebSphere, and has user and group rights to the aforementioned directory, so I don't think it is permission issue for error shown below.

If we tell FileReadingMessageSource  to use dummy directory, say 'lljljh', it creates this directory in WebSphere's app server here: /apps/WebSphere/AppServer-8.5/profiles/AppSrv01/lljljh. Maybe it is a WebSphere setting that needs to be set to be allowed to work outside the app server directory?

On Windows, it worked fine with the test structure C:\cvs\ssn\archive, which was also outside of the web application for the Tomcat container we were testing on

We get the error when using this code:

```
@Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "ssnInboundFileChannel", poller = @Poller(cron="${mec/SSN_POLLER}"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileMessageSourceSSN() {
     System.out.println("Creating bean definition for ssnInboundFileChannel");
     FileReadingMessageSource source = initialSetUp();
     source.setDirectory(new File(mecProperty.getProperty(MecConstants.SSN_SFTP_WORKING_DIR)));
     System.out.println("enter fileMessageSource in following dir....." + mecProperty.getProperty(MecConstants.SSN_SFTP_WORKING_DIR));
     return source;
    }


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source directory [/users/chroot/mecssn/incoming/archive] does not exist.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.onInit(FileReadingMessageSource.java:237)
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 82 more
```

***UPDATE***

Turned out to be a permissions issue. These permissions fixed it:

```
drwxrws--- 4 mecssn wasadm   4096 Sep 17 17:19 .
drwxr-x--- 3 root   mecssn   4096 Aug 27 15:05 ..
drwx------ 2 wasadm sftpchrt 4096 Sep 17 17:19 archive
drwxrwx--- 2 wasadm wasadm   4096 Sep 14 17:01 logs
```

The key was the chmod g+s incoming

Supposedly this is a known issue with WAS application server. As WASADM being part of group mecssn it is only at the UNIX session. But when Nodeagent starts Java app from console it does not read the WASADM groupset. It only sees WASADM account and its primary group which is WASADM.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question here? Maybe this is already as a candidate to be removed?..